# Active Directory: trigger API call when a user is added/removed to SG

Tags: active-directory

Does Active Directory provide a capability to make an api call following an event of subscribe / unsubscribe from a security group? 
I’d prefer to not having to poll AD but rather have my code invoked afer an event of modification of subscript in AD.

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt if there is such default functionality in AD for any such case!

Comment: Not that I know of. What will your event be doing? Maybe there is another way.

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep in sync AD groups memberships and groups defined in an external tool (unfortunately the two are not integrated). I’m now thinking about polling AD every n minutes to detect changes, but it seems a waste of resources.

Comment: AD already sends out emails for new subscriptions, does that functionality allow to be customized and perform and other action?

Comment: @StefanoGallotti - AD doesn't send any email for any kind of subscription! It must be some managed application (developed by your team members) which does it on behalf of such event change in AD. Again, I'd say that you need to write custom code to manage such things.